Vue 2 whitespace handling in template
I have an project vue 2.7.14 + vite 5.2.11. I find out that template add extra spaces when use next formatting:
<span>
  {{ text }}
</span>

The result I get is:
<span> text </span>.
The result that should be:
<span>text</span>.
Vue 3 with the same vite version compiles this code correct.
The solution to get desired result is to use next formatting:
<span>{{
  text
}}</span>

but it lowers the readability when code is more complex:
<span>
  {{ text }}
  <span>
    {{ anotherText }}
  </span>
</span>

in vue 2 it renders to <span> text <span> anotherText </span></span> and in vue 3 it's  <span>text (extra space)<span>anotherText</span></span>.
I should use this to get desired result in both vue versions but it lowers the readability:
<span>{{ text
  }}<span>{{ 
    anotherText 
  }}</span></span
>

The desired result is <span>text<span>anotherText</span></span>.
Any ideas how I can stay with good readability and get a desired result?

Are you sure this is a Vue issue? Are you able to show an example result and your css? Here is a codepen with similar whitespace and the gaps collapse https://codepen.io/EightArmsHQ/pen/PovGYmN/5ea82595275b3a528a41dfcde7b6b0e4

I assume the browser would ignore those spaces no?

No, you can test it. I tried vue 2 and vue 3, vue 3 ignores white spaces in the beginning and in the end. Vue 2 doesn't ignore it and renders it.
